# Pandas df.replace() replacing all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program to look through rows, and reformat/replace incorrect sizes.

For instance:

| Option2 Value | Shirt Color | Actual Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L | Yellow | XL |
| XL | Black | 2XL |
| 2XL | Green | 3XL |

So I'm using some code to go through the dataframe from a CSV and replace the documented size with the actual size.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if df.loc[index, 'Documented Size''] == 'L':
       df['Documented Size'].replace(to_replace=['L'], value='XL', inplace=True)
   elif df.loc[index, 'Documented Size''] == 'XL':
       df['Documented Size'].replace(to_replace=['XL'], value='2XL', inplace=True)
```

However, it just seems to replace ALL entries of 'Documented Size' with the first 'if,' like so:

| Option2 Value | Shirt Color | Actual Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XL | Yellow | XL |
| XL | Black | 2XL |
| XL | Green | 3XL |

Comment: Everytime you want to use `iterrows`, stop and avoid. This is not the right to work with `dataframe`.

Comment: I think create dictionary and then use `replace`, no loops necessary.